# Dual basis for $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

How one can find dual basis for  $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$?

Thank you.

Comment: ...just the beginning.

Comment: What's the vector space (real/complex/rational/ polynomials of degree up to three)?

Comment: Polynomials of degree up to three

Comment: What is the definition of inner product? What is dual basis? How to find dual basis? Answer the above questions one by one. You can find the solution.

Comment: @eccstartup: What do inner products have to do with anything?

Comment: @ChrisEagle It is another way of expressing `f(x)` or `x(f)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that, for a finitely generated $\mathbf K$-vector space $V$ and a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, the dual basis is that set $\{v_1^*,\ldots,v_n^*\}$ of linear functionals in $\hom(V,\mathbf{K})$ such that
$$v_j^*(v_k)=\delta_{jk}$$

If you take $\mathbf{R}[x]_3$ as the vector space of polynomials of degree at most three, with his canonical basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ you have to look for linear functions $X_d:\mathbf{R}[x]_3\to\mathbf R$ for $d=0,1,2,3$ such that $X_d(x^k)=\delta_{dk}$. A good choice is the following: for every polynomial $p\in\mathbf{R}[x]_3$
$$X_0(p)=p(0)$$
$$X_1(p)=\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}x}(0)$$
$$X_2(p)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}^2p}{\mathrm{d}x^2}(0)$$
$$X_3(p)=\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}^3p}{\mathrm{d}x^3}(0)$$

Recall that a $m$-derivation $$\frac {\mathrm{d}^m}{\mathrm{d}t^m}:\mathbf{R}[t]\longrightarrow \mathbf{R}$$is a linear map and evaluation too!

(Please note that in this case a basis exists in the *ordinary sense* because the base vector space has finite dimension!)

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: This is weird: this is the same answer jibounet wrote one hour sooner...

Answer (score 4):

$\lbrace 1,X,X^{2},X^{3} \rbrace$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}_{3}[X]$. A polynomial of $\mathbb{R}_{3}[X]$ writes :

$$ P(X) = a_{0} + a_{1}X + a_{2}X^{2} + a_{3}X^{3} $$

where, for all $k \in \lbrace 0,\ldots,3 \rbrace$, you have :

$$ a_{k} = \frac{P^{(k)}(0)}{k!} $$

(which follows from the Taylor formula)

If you know the definition of dual basis, the rest is easy.

Comment: I'm not sure I can see what's the relation between the Taylor form of the coefficients when the polynomial is developed around $\;x=0\;$ and the question...

Comment: It was just to say that, if the dual basis is $(f_{i})_{1 \leq i \leq 4}$, then $f_{i}(P)=\frac{P^{(i-1)}(0)}{(i-1)!}$.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. Nice. +1 ...though the relation between both things is, I think, rather circumstancial.

Comment: You should probably call that the "standard" basis rather than the "canonical" one. (I'm being fussy because there is a definition of "canonical basis", although admittedly I don't think it applies to this situation).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $\,V:=\Bbb R_3[x]=$ all the real polynomials of degree $\,\le 3\;$ , you need the elements $\,f_i\in V^*\;,\;i=1,2,3,4\;$ s.t if we write $\,v_1=1\,,\,v_2=x\,,\,v_3=x^2\,,\,v_4=x^3\;$, then

$$f_i(v_j):=\begin{cases}1&,\;\;\text{if}\;\;i=j\\{}\\0&,\;\;\text{if}\;\;i\ne j\end{cases}$$

and extend the definition by linearity. For example:

$$f_2(1)=0\;,\;f_2(x)=1\;,\;f_2(x^2)=0\;,\;f_2(x^3)=0\implies \forall\,w:=a_1+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3\;,\;$$

$$f_2w=a_1$$

and etc.

Comment: Please excuse me - how looks like that basis? I don't get it.

Comment: Simple: the dual basis is $\;\{f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4\}\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

In general if $$V=Span\lbrace u_1,...u_n \rbrace$$ then the basis of $V'$ corresponding to the linearly independent vectors $u_1,...u_n$ is given by $$V' = Span\lbrace l_1,...l_n\rbrace $$ such that $$l_i(u_j) = \delta_{ij} = \left\lbrace \begin{array}{cc} 1 & i=j \\ 0 & i\neq j \\\end{array} \right. $$ Carry out the calculations and you are done!